# Empty button click event still triggering something

Tags: c#, events, button

I have multiple button click events which are empty but when I click on the buttons associated with them they still update a UI element. The code to update the UI element is also empty.

So essentially I'm clicking an empty click event to run a function which is also empty yet I'm still seeing some output even when there's no output to give.

Like what? What the hell is going on...

I don't really know what to say because this doesn't make any sense. I would show you some code but there's literally no code to show you because there isn't any. Yet somehow this absence of code is still doing something!

Edit: I realise what has happened. Visual studio has decided to just ignore my code. Like I can comment out a print statement and it will still show.

I can build my program even with syntax errors. So I don't know what's wrong but it could be something with the compiler or something as it isn't building properly.

Comment: Explain _update a UI element._ ! Also: You can use the debugger to step though code..

Comment: @Michal : Well he clearly stated that there __is__ no code.

Comment: If you have configured it to do something and then removed it, it might be that you have to Clean and Rebuild your code (or even delete manually your bin directory). From your description it looks like that you have some cached code that isn't up-to-date.